# webhook api call windows auth

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I set webhook (async call) service bus to call rest API with windows auth.
using admin account.
but request to API comes as anonymous, so it works only if I set Anonymous auth - enabled in API.

is there a bug?

Comment: did you take a look at this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/use-webhooks?view=op-9-1)

Comment: @AnkUser, yes, I figured out. user , specified in webhook is used to gather data, request sent anonimus, can use header to hardcode token or basic auth. so inconvenient . thank you